# How to deploy shield with Kibana on Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ssl, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, kibana-4

I am trying to deploy Kibana on Bluemix PaaS. Because Kibana is a Node.js application, it can be deployed as such on Bluemix. All i have to do:

1. Provide a simple `manifest.yml` file that details the app name and a couple of other things
2. Provide a `Procfile` that has just one line as `web: bin/kibana --port=$PORT`

Thus, I can run Kibana on Bluemix. Note that this is pushed via Cloud Foundry.

Also, I was able to install the `marvel` and `sense` plugins for Kibana.

Now, I installed the `shield` plugin. This plugin requires an `ssl key` and an `ssl cert` file to run. The path to these files must be provided in the `kibana.yml` file.

After installation, I tested the shield plugin natively and it worked just fine.

Here is the layout of the directory structure:

```
bin(d)
config(d)
installedPlugins(d)
node_modules(d)
sslFiles(d)
manifest.yml
Procfile
```

(d) represents directories. The `sslFiles` folder contains the `ssl key` and `ssl cert` files.

Before I could push to Bluemix, I knew that the paths to the SSL files would have to be relative to the app in Bluemix. Thus, in the `kibana.yml` file, I specified them as:

```
kibana.ssl.key:app/sslFiles/kibana.key
kibana.ssl.cert:app/sslFiles/kibana.cert
```

I did this as in Bluemix, I could see the following directory structure:

```
app(d)
    bin(d)
    config(d)
    installedPlugins(d)
    node_modules(d)
    sslFiles(d)
    manifest.yml
    Procfile
```

Indentation represents containment. So, I pushed it to Bluemi using Cloud Foundry, but now I get a `502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request` error. I tried changing the paths to `sslFiles/kibana.key` but then I got a `cannot find path sslFiles/kibana.key` staging error.

What is responsible for my 502 error? Is it the path to the sslFiles? If so, how can I properly provide the paths?

Comment: If you need absolute paths, and I don't know if you do or not, you might try adding a post install script to your package.json which updates the paths in your kibana.yml with the value of the `HOME` environment variable.

Comment: what does the HOME env variable refer to in context of bluemix? is it a system variable or do i have to define it? plus is there any way i can use something like $HOME in the yml file?

Comment: `HOME` refers to the root folder of the deployed application. It is set by Cloud Foundry. The value is something like /home/vcap/app. Or you can set your own env vars to whatever value you want.

Comment: thanks! that is really helpful. is there a way to get the value of the HOME variable? is it always fixed for all cloudfoundry applications?